# Objective - c - Pointers and what really happens when you assign an array to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

So I am wondering what happens when I do

```
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arr1 addobject:ob1];

arr2 = arr1;

[self changeValue:[arr2 objectAtIndex:2]]; //function that will modify what is sent to it
```

1) Can I even do = between to nsmutablearrays?
2) If I were to access the object in arr1, would it be modified?
3) How deep it is? - If I were to access that object from somewhere else, would it be modified?
4) I'm assuming using mutableCopy would return an entirely new array. 
5) is there anyway to simulate this deep linking/connecting?  For example, if I wanted to assign the same object to 2 different arrays, so that if I modified one, it would change that object in both arrays?
6) What is the word that stands for this?  I don't think it's linking/connecting.

Thanks so much
-James

Comment: Please trim down the number of questions you ask per post.

Comment: I ordinarily agree with the principle of not asking too many questions at once, but these questions are so intertwined that I think they do belong together. Asking them each in separate questions would be obnoxiously repetitious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're confusing objects and variables. You don't assign one object to another; you assign objects to variables. Variables are just a way to keep sight of an object, which otherwise would be floating off somewhere in your program's memory space. Two variables can point to the same object, and when this happens, yes, you'll see changes to the object through both variables, because *it's the same object*.

When you do `arr2 = arr1`, you're having arr2 point to the same array arr1 does. So if you change something in arr1, will you see it in arr2? Yes, because **arr2 *is* arr1**. It's the same object, just called two different names.

If instead it had been `arr2 = [arr1 mutableCopy]`, yes, that would create a new array object, so the two variables would be pointing to different objects. If you add an object to one array, it does not magically get added to the other. But this raises the question: What if arr1 contained a bunch of NSMutableStrings? Would changing one of the strings in arr1 also change the corresponding string in arr2? Yes, because even though the array itself is a different object, it still contains the same objects as the original array.

So the way to think about this isn't as two arrays being somehow linked or connected. The only question you need to ask is, "Are these objects that I'm interacting with in two places the same object or different ones?"

Comment: You're saying that if I do arr2= [arr1 mutableCopy], and arr2 has all nsmutablestring's, Then i change all the strings in arr2...all of the strings are changed in arr1 as well??

Comment: @James: If you modify the strings themselves (such as adding "A wise man once said" to the beginning of all of them), then yes, because it's the same strings in both arrays. But if you take a string out of one array, that will only happen to that one array — because that is a change to the array itself, not to the string.

Comment: hmm. so dangerous!  so then to get an entirely separate copy, I'd need to do a recursive mutableCopy call to all objects in arr1?

Comment: @James: Pretty much. But in general, it is better to solve this in your design: If you avoid sharing mutable state whenever possible, you avoid the issue altogether. Only one piece of code should be responsible for a bit of data, and anybody else who wants to do something with that data should have to go through the data's owner. Otherwise it can just get really messy over time.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks.  I'll work on some redesign